# Making Jquery continue to next song

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make it so that after the song in the audio player finishes it will go to another MP3 that we have set in javascript, how can I go about doing this? 2nd MP3 will be set as `<?php echo isset( $_GET['mp32'] ) ? $_GET['mp32'] : ''; ?>`

```
<audio class="audio" autoplay controls>
    <source src="<?php echo isset( $_GET['mp3'] ) ? $_GET['mp3'] : ''; ?>">
</audio>
```

Comment: @j08691 my bad, don't need that.

Comment: listen to the end event and play the next song